# Pareto efficient quantity of public good (quasi-linear preferences)

Tags: microeconomics, public-goods

I am doing a question on finding the Pareto efficient quantity of a public good. Instead of using the condition $\sum MRS_i = c'(G)$ where $c(G)$ denotes the cost of the public good, it asks you to find the efficient quantity by maximising the sum of the agents' utilities. Apparently this is only valid if preferences are quasi-linear so whilst I can do the question I do not understand why this is a valid approach. Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/11033/quasilinear-utility-pareto-optimality-implies-total-utility-maximization

Comment: It is not true that maximising the sum of utilities yields a Pareto optimum only when utility is quasi-linear. Indeed, suppose we found an outcome that maximises the sum of everyone's utility. Then, by definition, any alternative choice must yield a weakly lower $\sum u$—meaning there must be a lower $u$ for at least one agent. It follows that the alternative does not Pareto dominate the original, utility-sum-maximising choice. What *is* true is that if utility is quasi-linear then *every* Pareto optimum maximises the sum of utilities.

Comment: @Ubiquitous - I don't think it is true that if utility is quasi-linear then every Pareto optimum maximizes the sum of utilities. Refer to my answer for the counter example: http://economics.stackexchange.com/a/15582/11824

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is true in a standard public good economy the question is referring to. Consider the following counterexample:

Suppose $I  = \{1,2\}$ and utility of the individual $i$ depends on his consumption of public good $(G)$ and private good $x_i$: $u_1(G, x_1) = 2\sqrt{G} + x_1$ and $u_2(G, x_2) = 2\sqrt{G} + x_2$,

Also, the CRS technology used for production of public good uses private good as input:
$G = f(x_0) = x_0$.

If the society has only 4 units of private good in the beginning, then the set of feasible allocations can be written as

$\{(G, x_1, x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^3_+: G+x_1+x_2 = 4\}$.

Notice that the allocation $a_1 = (G, x_1, x_2) = (1,3,0)$ is Pareto efficient, but does not maximize the sum of utilities. The reason is that allocation $a_2 = (G, x_1, x_2) = (4,0,0)$ yields the higher sum.

$\color{blue}{u_1(1,3) + u_2(1,0)} = 5+2 =7 \color{blue}{<} 8 = 4 + 4 = \color{blue}{u_1(4,0) + u_2(4,0)}$.

*Added later*: Here is the video of how we can find the set of all efficient allocations for a similar problem, the only difference is that the total endowment of private good is given 10 in this video:

[Representing set of all feasible allocations in a Dolbear Triangle](https://youtu.be/GPahrOHjUs4)

[Finding set of all efficient allocations](https://youtu.be/g1gOVshgYGM)

Comment: Quasi-linear utility implies that utility is transferable. So in fact, $a_2$ can be a Pareto improvement from $a_1$ if individual 2 agrees to switch to $a_2$ and transfers $1$ unit of $x$ to individual 1. This way, individual 1 is no worse than in $a_1$ (he gets $4+1=5$), but individual 2 is strictly better off even after the transfer (he gets $4-1=3>2$)..

Comment: Individual 2 does not have any private good to transfer to individual 1 at $a_1$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I missed that, and I assumed utility were transferable.

Answer (score 0):

The Lindahl Equilibrium $y^*$ with quasi-linear preferences is uniquely determined. That is, $y^*$ is independent of individual consumption levels of $x$

Comment: Is there a way of understanding this without using the Lindahl equilibrium approach? (If not I will just have to learn what it is.)